# Reverse-calculating original data from a known moving average

Tags: matlab, moving-average

I'm trying to estimate the (unknown) original datapoints that went into calculating a (known) moving average. However, I do know *some* of the original datapoints, and I'm not sure how to use that information.

I am using the method given in the answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67907/extract-data-points-from-moving-average, but in MATLAB (my code below). This method works quite well for large numbers of data points (>1000), but less well with fewer data points, as you'd expect.

```
window = 3;
datapoints = 150;
data = 3*rand(1,datapoints)+50;
moving_averages = [];
for i = window:size(data,2)
    moving_averages(i) = mean(data(i+1-window:i));
end

length = size(moving_averages,2)+(window-1);
a = (tril(ones(length,length),window-1) - tril(ones(length,length),-1))/window;
a = a(1:length-(window-1),:);
ai = pinv(a);

daily = mtimes(ai,moving_averages');

x = 1:size(data,2);
figure(1)
hold on
plot(x,data,'Color','b');
plot(x(window:end),moving_averages(window:end),'Linewidth',2,'Color','r');
plot(x,daily(window:end),'Color','g');
hold off
axis([0 size(x,2) min(daily(window:end))-1 max(daily(window:end))+1])
legend('original data','moving average','back-calculated')
```

Now, say I know a smattering of the original data points. I'm having trouble figuring how might I use that information to more accurately calculate the rest. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to calculate the original data exactly if you at any time can exactly determine one window's worth of data, i.e. in this case n-1 samples in a window of length n. (In your case) if you know A,B and (A+B+C)/3, you can solve now and know C. Now when you have (B+C+D)/3 (your moving average) you can exactly solve for D. Rinse and repeat. This logic works going backwards too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the [same idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68002/170):

```
% the actual vector of values
a = cumsum(rand(150,1) - 0.5);

% compute moving average
win = 3;  % sliding window length
idx = hankel(1:win, win:numel(a));
m = mean(a(idx));

% coefficient matrix: m(i) = sum(a(i:i+win-1))/win
A = repmat([ones(1,win) zeros(1,numel(a)-win)], numel(a)-win+1, 1);
for i=2:size(A,1)
    A(i,:) = circshift(A(i-1,:), [0 1]);
end
A = A / win;

% solve linear system
%x = A \ m(:);
x = pinv(A) * m(:);

% plot and compare
subplot(211), plot(1:numel(a),a, 1:numel(m),m)
legend({'original','moving average'})
title(sprintf('length = %d, window = %d',numel(a),win))
subplot(212), plot(1:numel(a),a, 1:numel(a),x)
legend({'original','reconstructed'})
title(sprintf('error = %f',norm(x(:)-a(:))))
```

[image: result]

You can see the reconstruction error is very small, even using the data sizes in your example (150 samples with a 3-samples moving average).